# replace a string after substring found in jython/python

Tags: python, string, jython, str-replace

I have a string like this

```
ABC/AAAA DEF/78kkk OBJ/89KKK KLE/67899
```

and I pass the substring to find and replace after. so If I pass DEF/00012 and the original string
should be replaced as like this

```
ABC/AAAA DEF/00012 OBJ/89KKK KLE/67899
```

I have tried with string.replace('DEF', 'DEF/00012')

I would get the output as

```
ABC/AAAA DEF/00012/78kkk OBJ/89KKK KLE/67899
```

any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replace('DEF/78kkk', 'DEF/00012')
```

If you mean by "substring" is that the succeeding characters after "DEF" is  not fixed to a specific value, use regular expressions instead.

```
result = re.sub("DEF/\w+", "DEF/00012", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
txt = 'ABC/AAAA DEF/78kkk OBJ/89KKK KLE/67899'
change = 'DEF'
changeto = 'DEF/00012'
newtxt = ' '.join(changeto if i.startswith(change) else i for i in txt.split(' '))
print(newtxt)
```

Output:

```
ABC/AAAA DEF/00012 OBJ/89KKK KLE/67899
```

I splitted at spaces and changed part beginning with `DEF`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there really is a blank space after every "substring" you will have to use re:

```py
import re
your_string = re.sub("DEF/*$", "DEF/00012", your_string)
```